# Complex logarithm and Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck with a little exercise I wanted to do in order to check I understand the complex logarithm. This is defined as 
$$
\log z := \ln |z| + i \arg(z) \qquad \text{for } z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus ( - \infty, 0]
$$
where $\arg(z)$ is the principal argument, that is the unique angle $\theta \in ( - \pi, \pi]$ that satisfies the equation $z = |z|e^{i \arg(z)}$.

Now the logarithm is holomorphic, so by the Cauchy integral formula we can see that for $a \in \mathbb{C} \setminus ( - \infty, 0]$ we have
$$
\log a = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C_r} \frac{\log \lambda}{\lambda - a} \,d\lambda
$$
where $C_r$ is a circular contour, traversed anticlockwise, centered at $a$ of radius $r$ small enough such that it does not intersect the ray $(-\infty, 0]$.

I wanted to check this "by hand", i.e. via parametrization. So let $\lambda = a + e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$. Then the contour integral turns into
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C_r} \frac{\log \lambda}{\lambda - a} \, d\lambda &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log (a + re^{it}) \,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi } \int^{2\pi}_0 \ln |\,a + r e^{it}| \,dt + \frac{i}{2 \pi } \int^{2 \pi}_0 \arg(a + re^{it})\,dt\,.
\end{align}
I argue that the second term is zero , as one can see by inspection ( we traverse a circle that does not enclose the orgin, since $a \ne 0$) - is this correct? Then I struggle with calculating the first term explicitly, in particular I am worried that something is wrong already since the result would be a real number whereas $log a$ is complex in general... thanks for hints and tips!!

Comment: For small enough $r$, $\arg (a+re^{it})$ is approximately constant $\arg a$, and $\log \lvert a+re^{it}\rvert$ approximately constant $\log \lvert a\rvert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer uuggh .. that makes sense. Thanks!!